# Is F included in F+?

Tags: database-design, dependencies

The definition in my book says:

> *The set of all functional dependencies logically implied by F is the closure of F.*

My question is, do we include FDs in F in F closure as well ?

If I have:

- `F = {A→B, B→C}`
- a) `F+ = {A→C, A→BC, A→B, B→C}`
- b) `F+ = {A→C, A→BC}`

Which one would be correct a) or b) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each dependency implies itself (given the fact that in logic trivially every assertion implies itself), `F` is included in `F+`. But note that in your example `F+` contains quite a large number of dependencies, in addition to the dependencies that you have listed, like for instance `A→A`, `AB→C`, `B→B`, `AC→A`, etc.